# Procedure for getting an output of a def function code in python version 3

Tags: program-entry-point, function

I am attempting to do practice problems of how a def function code works. Although I believe my procedure so far is not correct. 
Here is the code:

```
def main():
    max=0
    getMax(1,2,max)
    print(max)

def getMax(v1,v2,max):
    if (v1>v2):
        max=v1
    else:
        max=v2
main()
```

And here is my reasoning through it.

Execution of the main function begins where max=0. The next line has initialized the (local variable?) `getMax`. `v1` is replaced with 1, `v2` is placed with 2, and `max` is replaced with 0. Going back to the main function, python prints `max` which is 0. Which is why the output is 0. The main function is now finished, and it returns the control to its caller(which is `main()`). 
Is my procedure correct?
What is messing me up is I usually see the `getMax`(or the local variable I think it's called) first before I see the `def main()` function. does order matter here? Because the if loop was completely ignored in my opinion in the `def main` function.

Answer (score 0):

the argument `max` in the function `getMax()` gets a *copy* of the value of the variable `max` in `main()`.  Changes there are not propagated back to the caller.

Comment: Is that all I got wrong in my interpretation then? Also I still don't understand if order matters when it comes to the def function.